# Django HTTP Post Request from iOS

Tags: ios, django, http

I'm using the Django REST Framework.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def image_params(request, format=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.DATA
        size = request.POST.get('size')
        colour = request.POST.get('colour')
        get_clothes = Clothes.objects.filter( Q(clothescolour=colour) | Q(clothessize=size))
        serializer = ClothesSerializer(get_clothes, many=True)
        result = serializer.data
        print result
    return Response(result,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

I am sending a POST request using the POSTMAN client where in `form-data` the `key` is `colour` and the `value` is `red`. It works perfectly and I get the expected result. This is what `print request.DATA` looks like:

```
<QueryDict: {u'colour': [u'red']}>
```

When I send an actual request from iOS, `print request.DATA` looks as shown and my filter query fails.

```
{u'colour': u'red'}
```

Here is how I construct the HTTP Post Request in iOS:

```
NSDictionary* requestData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"red",
                             @"colour",
                             nil];

NSError *postError;
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&postError];
[postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[postRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
[postRequest setValue:@"application/json;charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With POSTMAN you're sending form data and with iOS you send json data instead.
That's why it is parsed differently.
You need to set `Content-Type: application/json` header on POSTMAN and send raw data:

> {"color": "black"}

This way you will get the same dict format on both.